# Return true or Return false. It gives me an error

Tags: operator-keyword

Tring to do this, but it does not seem right. What is wrong?

```
return CrossSystemString.Substring(CrossSystemString.Length - 6) == "union " ? true : false;
```

Comment: What language is this supposed to be?

Comment: You probably need to put parentheses around the predicate, also, if you just keep the predicate code and remove the `? :` bit, it will have the same value true/false

Comment: And what error are you getting?

Comment: This is an operator precedence error. You need to surround your the == and both parameters in parenthesis.

Comment: You could probably simplify this to `return (CrossSystemString.Substring(CrossSystemString.Length - 6) == "union")`

Answer (score 1):

Check the length of the string is greater than 6 or not

```
if(CrossSystemString.length > 6)
     return CrossSystemString.Substring(CrossSystemString.Length - 6) 
            == "union" ? true : false;
else
    return false;
```